# What was Ging trying to accomplish at the election of the 13th Chairman?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

What was Ging trying to accomplish at the election of the 13th Chairman? It seemed that he had a plan and that everything went according to it, excepting the part where Pariston resigned from his position of Chairman. What was his full plan and what was he truly trying to accomplish (his final target)? Did he really wanted Pariston to be the 13th Chairman or his plan had a continuation?

Comment: I think his plan is to prevent Pariston to be the 13th Chairman,  but i dont know the full plan.

Comment: @Marcio.Rezende it means that his plan failed, because in the end Pariston became the 13th Chairman... but after seeing Gon entering the voting hall he said: "I knew that's gonna happen... but still this doesn't make it easier". Which means that he had everything under control (even Gon's coming). Who knows... probably he wasn't expecting for Gon to vote for Pariston in the end. That's what "probably" has broken the course of his plans.

Comment: thas true, probably he wants to find some one to made the same role of Pariston when he was the second of Netero? Netero choose Pariston because he is very different of him self, to have a balance, but i dont know how Ging will interfere in this or if hes do all this in the Neteros name, some special request maybe. I dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ging's actions I like to think he wanted to have some fun. He just wanted to manipulate people into doing something he had already predicted. Like Pariston he didn't have his eyes on the presidential seat. His interactions with Cheadle, Leorio etc. seem to be always aimed towards creating chaos.

I think this line sums up his motivations in the 12th election

> "If I can get my target to move as I want, I've succeeded as a Hunter." - Ging Freecs